# Can an ESB provide an EJB2.0 and EJB3.0 interface in parallel?

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb, esb, ejb-2.x, jboss-esb

Today I received an email, which announced that a service will be migrated from EJB2.0 to EJB3.0 and the EJB2.0 interface won't be supported further. But as we're using an Enterprise Service Bus, I was wondering why they don't provide both interfaces in parallel. In theory an ESB makes a service available in a technology independent manner.

Is it possible to create an EJB3.0 Service and add an EJB2.0 adapter without extra coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESB is meant to provide you these features.  It hides you from the changes made by the service implementers.

If the interface to the service changes, you need to add a mediation component which maps the old interface to new interface and provides the same old interface to the client application using the services of ESB.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Chris,Mediations can be built using the ESB tools. I don't know the ESB tools that you use. I use WESB and WMQ and they work along with other tools like WTX to do this job of interface mapping ,data mapping etc. Mediations being key functionality of any ESB any tool that you use would provide you with the base to build your mediation(s). I would suggest you look at the specific product doco. This article might help in getting the big picture right - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1105_flurry/1105_flurry.html